# What sprockets mean in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, sprockets

So, I just realised that I have absolutely no Idea what Sprockets are in rails.

when using either bootstrap, or materialize, it is requested to include the `sprocket` (bootstrap-sprocket or materialize-sprocket) in the `application.js` file.

Everything I search talks about the asset pipeline and confuses me the more.

According to ruby-guides,

> The asset pipeline is technically no longer a core feature of Rails 4, it has been extracted out of the framework into the sprockets-rails gem.

and when I did `bundle show sprockets-rails`, I got:

```
/Users/Sunday/workspace/resilience/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.1
```

which shows that I have the gem, at least.

But my confusion and my question is that what is the importance of `sprockets`, as opposed to `sprockets-rails` that made other gems like `bootstrap` and `materialize` and probably some others to have `sprockets`, especially in their javascript files?

Thanks.

Comment: [Sprockets is a Ruby library for compiling and serving web assets. It features declarative dependency management for JavaScript and CSS assets, as well as a powerful preprocessor pipeline that allows you to write assets in languages like CoffeeScript, Sass, SCSS and LESS.](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Sprockets is a Ruby library for compiling and serving web assets. Sprockets allows to organize  an application’s JavaScript files into smaller more manageable chunks that can be distributed over a number of directories and files. It provides structure and practices on how to include assets in our projects.

Using directives at the start of each JavaScript file, Sprockets can determine which files a JavaScript file depends on. When it comes to deploying your application, Sprockets then uses these directives to turn your multiple JavaScript files into a single file for better performance.

Comment: sorry for the followup question, but is it correct that sprockets is only reliable for the javascrpt files. No other types like css, right?

Answer (score 10):

```
/app/assets/javascripts/application.js
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into including all the files listed below.
// Add new JavaScript/Coffee code in separate files in this directory and they'll automatically
// be included in the compiled file accessible from http://example.com/assets/application.js
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// the compiled file.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

`application.js` file is known as a manifest and it’s managed internally by `Sprockets`. When a request comes in for this file `Sprockets` looks at the manifest and **compiles** together every file that is mentioned in it and includes their contents before any code in this file.
`Sprockets` will search the `loadpath` for this file and, in this case, load it from the `jquery-rails` engine’s `vendor/asset/javascripts` directory.

Comment: This is a great explanation. What exactly is the loadpath?

Comment: loadpath is simply the path of the file that you list.