# Rails app: require bootstrap vs require bootstrap-sprockets

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-sass

What is the **consequential** difference between adding

```
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
```

and

```
//= require bootstrap
```

to application.js?

The [documentation](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass) says:

> bootstrap-sprockets provides individual Bootstrap Javascript files
>   (alert.js or dropdown.js, for example), while bootstrap provides a
>   concatenated file containing all Bootstrap Javascripts

Does one offer better performance over the other, or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Require `bootstrap` over `bootstrap-sprockets` for faster compilation.

Require `bootstrap-sprockets` over `bootstrap` for ease of debugging.

> While `bootstrap-sprockets` provides individual Bootstrap components for ease of debugging, you may alternatively require the concatenated `bootstrap` for faster compilation

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem#a-ruby-on-rails

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes ago, I asked [this question as to what sprockets means in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31828795/what-sprockets-mean-in-rails). Which drew in two very good answers to throw more light into the topic for me.

I'm sure by the time you go through the answers, you will get more understanding.

Comment: Thanks. I think I get sprockets now. But rails apps seem run the same having required either bootstrap or bootstrap-sprockets in application.js. My question is what's the consequential difference.