# Difference between // and //= in application.js?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In every language I can think of, placing the comment decorator at the start of a line will comment out that line of code (without any exceptions).

In rails, in `application.js` I see some lines starting with `//` and others starting with `//=`. I presume lines starting with `//` are comments and those lines are not executed.

#### Question

What's the difference between

- lines starting with `//`
- lines starting with `//=` and
- lines starting with neither of those decorators?

Comment: ``//`` are standard Javascript comments. Sprockets uses ``//=`` as processor directives (see [here](https://github.com/rails/sprockets#directives) for a description). Lines that don't start with a comment are...code.

Comment: No, require (in this usage) is purely a Sprockets thing. It tells Sprockets to add the referenced file to the concatenated file at that point. They don't 'run' at that point; it's a compilation directive.

Comment: Thanks, @rmlockerd if you want to make it an answer, I will accept it. I have added an answer with what I have learned so far

Answer (score 2):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31829665/5783745):

> Sprockets is a Ruby library for compiling and serving web assets. Sprockets allows to organize an application’s JavaScript files into smaller more manageable chunks that can be distributed over a number of directories and files.

[Also](https://rossta.net/blog/why-does-rails-install-both-webpacker-and-sprockets.html):

> When it comes to asset bundling, the "Rails way" is webpack for JavaScript and Sprockets for everything else. The default setup in a fresh Rail 6 install, similar to what Basecamp uses, still compiles CSS, images, and fonts with Sprockets.

So basically

- lines starting with `//=` is a sprocket processor directive (and it will get executed)
- lines starting with `//` are simply comments (they won't get executed), and
- lines starting with neither are javascript